# How can I type special quote/speech marks such as those used in Icelandic?

Tags: language-support, special-characters

When writing in English and we quote some one else we use these "double-quotes" which are available on the keyboard.

Some languages require different quoting styles, for example in Icelandic low and high quote marks are used „like this.“

In Windows it's is easy to produce these; you type <kbd>alt</kbd> + 0132 before and <kbd>alt</kbd> + 0147 after. This is so automatic for my fingers that I sometimes have to look up the numbers, my typing skills know them but my mind forgets them.

There must be a handy equivalent for mac and Linux users, no?

Comment: http://askdifferent.com is the Q&A site that's the equivalent to here for MacOS X.

Answer (score 4):

In Ubuntu you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and then type 201E for „ and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and type 201C for “.